# Insert multiple ids from table a into table b

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I want to select all ids from an existing table and insert them into a newly created table, in this sort of fashion:

```
INSERT INTO product_extend (product_id) VALUES (SELECT product_id FROM products)
```

Creating one new row per id. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: what are you getting by this query?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_extend (product_id) 
SELECT product_id FROM products;
```

As explained in [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) in MySQL Manual.